# Split Python list into several lists based on index

Tags: python, list

So I've got a string of bytes which represents cubes in three dimensions. The coordinates are ordered like this:

```
[x0y0z0, x0y1z0, x0y2z0, ..., x0y127z0, x0y0z1, x0y1z1, ..., x15y127z15]
```

I'd like to split this into 128 lists, one for each Y coordinate. [This code](http://github.com/l0b0/mian/blob/master/mian/mian.py#L207) already does that, but I think inefficiently. Is there some way to split this list based on mod(128) of the index?

From the [original code](http://github.com/l0b0/mian/commit/8c8aa68b45c777ad279e5d3fba99ce8015881939):

```
col.extend(izip_longest(*[iter(file["Level"]["Blocks"].value)]*128))
```

That takes quite a while, and I think it should be possible to make something better performing by avoiding the `*128` part of this. But zipping is definitely not my strong side, and neither is binary file handling.

Comment: Your example isn't clear. Is it a list of strings or a string? Why are you showing a y127? is this the 127'th y coordinate? I thought there were only 16.

Comment: This is ambiguous.  Please provide code showing actual input data (not pseudocode that requires interpretation), and the expected result from that data.

Comment: The `*128` part does not take long, you are just making 128 references to the same iterator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# l = [x0y0z0, ...]
def bucketsofun(l, sp=16):
  r = [[] for x in range(sp)]
  for b, e in itertools.izip(itertools.cycle(r), l):
    b.append(e)
  return r
```

Comment: Do you have more descriptive names for b and e?

Comment: `bucket` and `element`, if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might be worth trying

```
L = file["Level"]["Blocks"].value
col += [L[i::128] for i in range(127)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Itertools can do it too:

```
from itertools import izip, izip_longest, chain

def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

# you have something like this
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
l = list(chain.from_iterable(range(5) for _ in range(5)))

# you want to put all the 0s, 1s (every 5th element) together
print list(izip(*grouper(5, l)))
# [(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1), ... , (4, 4, 4, 4, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Faster way to do this is using reshape() function from NumPy

```
original_1D_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
modulo = 3

new_2D_array = np.reshape(original_1D_array, (-1, modulo))

# new_2D_array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Now we just need to transpose this matrix

```
new_2D_array = new_2D_array.T

# new_2D_array = [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```